# Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, plyr, reshape

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this.

```
x a 1 
x b 2 
x c 3 
y a 3 
y b 3 
y c 2
```

I want this in matrix form so I can feed it to heatmap to make a plot.  The result should look something like:

```
    a    b    c
x   1    2    3
y   3    3    2
```

I have tried `cast` from the reshape package and I have tried writing a manual function to do this but I do not seem to be able to get it right.

Comment: @AnandaMahto also has a great answer about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515736/210673

Comment: @Jaap, how did you decide to close this one rather than the other? My answer here was meant to be an authoritative answer to this commonly asked question, and in my opinion, is much more useful than the grab bag of answers at the other question.

Comment: That the other question has a lot of answers, each highlighting a specific solution, doesn't make it worse than this one. So, how did I make the decision? Easy: the other question was asked earlier and has a lot of valueble answers.

Comment: @Jaap: Sigh. The culture here still confuses and frustrates me. At one point "authoritative" answers were preferred and timing of questions didn't matter. I think I need to stay "left" (as in my username).

Comment: Every so often I come back and check to see if Stack Overflow has changed for the better... not yet.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  This answer starts with what is quickly becoming the standard method, but also includes older methods and various other methods from answers to similar questions scattered around this site.

```
tmp <- data.frame(x=gl(2,3, labels=letters[24:25]),
                  y=gl(3,1,6, labels=letters[1:3]), 
                  z=c(1,2,3,3,3,2))
```

**Using the tidyverse:**

The new cool new way to do this is with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr 1.0.0`. It returns a data frame, which is probably what most readers of this answer will want. For a heatmap, though, you would need to convert this to a true matrix.

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(tmp, names_from = y, values_from = z)
## # A tibble: 2 x 4
## x         a     b     c
## <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 x       1     2     3
## 2 y       3     3     2
```

The old cool new way to do this is with `spread` from `tidyr`. It similarly returns a data frame.

```
library(tidyr)
spread(tmp, y, z)
##   x a b c
## 1 x 1 2 3
## 2 y 3 3 2
```

**Using reshape2**:

One of the first steps toward the tidyverse was the reshape2 package.

To get a matrix use `acast`:

```
library(reshape2)
acast(tmp, x~y, value.var="z")
##   a b c
## x 1 2 3
## y 3 3 2
```

Or to get a data frame, use `dcast`, as here: [Reshape data for values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8093839/210673).

```
dcast(tmp, x~y, value.var="z")
##   x a b c
## 1 x 1 2 3
## 2 y 3 3 2
```

**Using plyr**:

In between reshape2 and the tidyverse came `plyr`, with the `daply` function, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020101/210673

```
library(plyr)
daply(tmp, .(x, y), function(x) x$z)
##    y
## x   a b c
##   x 1 2 3
##   y 3 3 2
```

**Using matrix indexing:**

This is kinda old school but is a nice demonstration of matrix indexing, which can be really useful in certain situations.

```
with(tmp, {
  out <- matrix(nrow=nlevels(x), ncol=nlevels(y),
                dimnames=list(levels(x), levels(y)))
  out[cbind(x, y)] <- z
  out
})
```

**Using `xtabs`:**

```
xtabs(z~x+y, data=tmp)
```

**Using a sparse matrix:**

There's also `sparseMatrix` within the `Matrix` package, as seen here: [R - convert BIG table into matrix by column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9833052/210673)

```
with(tmp, sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(x), j=as.numeric(y), x=z,
                       dimnames=list(levels(x), levels(y))))
## 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##   a b c
## x 1 2 3
## y 3 3 2
```

**Using `reshape`:**

You can also use the base R function `reshape`, as suggested here: [Convert table into matrix by column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2126108/210673), though you have to do a little manipulation afterwards to remove an extra columns and get the names right (not shown).

```
reshape(tmp, idvar="x", timevar="y", direction="wide")
##   x z.a z.b z.c
## 1 x   1   2   3
## 4 y   3   3   2
```

Comment: `acast(tmp, x~y, value.var="z")` will give a matrix output, with `x` as the row.names

Comment: Can you comment on the advantages/disadvantages of different methods?

Comment: In most small data sets, the primary consideration should be coding in a way that is clear to future analysts (including future you) and the least susceptible to human coding mistakes. Although that will depend on your strengths and needs, generally this is considered one of the strengths of the new tidyverse set of packages. Another consideration (though not really an advantage/disadvantage) is whether you want a matrix or a data frame as a result; this question specifically asks for a matrix, and you can see in the answer that some techniques give that directly while some give a data frame.

Comment: Computing time may also be a consideration for large data sets, especially when the code needs to be repeated multiple times or on multiple data sets. I suspect that depends in part, though, on the specific characteristics of the data set. If that is a concern for you, I suggest asking another question about optimizing for your particular situation; questions like that at one point were like catnip for this crowd. :) But I'll repeat my previous point: optimizing for the user is (usually) more important than optimizing for the computer.

Answer (score 4):

The question is some years old but maybe some people are still interested in alternative answers.

If you don't want to load any packages, you might use this function:

```
#' Converts three columns of a data.frame into a matrix -- e.g. to plot 
#' the data via image() later on. Two of the columns form the row and
#' col dimensions of the matrix. The third column provides values for
#' the matrix.
#' 
#' @param data data.frame: input data
#' @param rowtitle string: row-dimension; name of the column in data, which distinct values should be used as row names in the output matrix
#' @param coltitle string: col-dimension; name of the column in data, which distinct values should be used as column names in the output matrix
#' @param datatitle string: name of the column in data, which values should be filled into the output matrix
#' @param rowdecreasing logical: should the row names be in ascending (FALSE) or in descending (TRUE) order?
#' @param coldecreasing logical: should the col names be in ascending (FALSE) or in descending (TRUE) order?
#' @param default_value numeric: default value of matrix entries if no value exists in data.frame for the entries
#' @return matrix: matrix containing values of data[[datatitle]] with rownames data[[rowtitle]] and colnames data[coltitle]
#' @author Daniel Neumann
#' @date 2017-08-29
data.frame2matrix = function(data, rowtitle, coltitle, datatitle, 
                             rowdecreasing = FALSE, coldecreasing = FALSE,
                             default_value = NA) {

  # check, whether titles exist as columns names in the data.frame data
  if ( (!(rowtitle%in%names(data))) 
       || (!(coltitle%in%names(data))) 
       || (!(datatitle%in%names(data))) ) {
    stop('data.frame2matrix: bad row-, col-, or datatitle.')
  }

  # get number of rows in data
  ndata = dim(data)[1]

  # extract rownames and colnames for the matrix from the data.frame
  rownames = sort(unique(data[[rowtitle]]), decreasing = rowdecreasing)
  nrows = length(rownames)
  colnames = sort(unique(data[[coltitle]]), decreasing = coldecreasing)
  ncols = length(colnames)

  # initialize the matrix
  out_matrix = matrix(NA, 
                      nrow = nrows, ncol = ncols,
                      dimnames=list(rownames, colnames))

  # iterate rows of data
  for (i1 in 1:ndata) {
    # get matrix-row and matrix-column indices for the current data-row
    iR = which(rownames==data[[rowtitle]][i1])
    iC = which(colnames==data[[coltitle]][i1])

    # throw an error if the matrix entry (iR,iC) is already filled.
    if (!is.na(out_matrix[iR, iC])) stop('data.frame2matrix: double entry in data.frame')
    out_matrix[iR, iC] = data[[datatitle]][i1]
  }

  # set empty matrix entries to the default value
  out_matrix[is.na(out_matrix)] = default_value

  # return matrix
  return(out_matrix)

}
```

How it works:

```
myData = as.data.frame(list('dim1'=c('x', 'x', 'x', 'y','y','y'),
                            'dim2'=c('a','b','c','a','b','c'),
                            'values'=c(1,2,3,3,3,2))) 

myMatrix = data.frame2matrix(myData, 'dim1', 'dim2', 'values')

myMatrix
>   a b c
> x 1 2 3
> y 3 3 2
```

Answer (score 4):

#### base R, `unstack`

```
unstack(df, V3 ~ V2)
#   a b c
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 3 3 2
```

This may not be a general solution but works well in this case.

#### data

```
df<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), V3 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness, there's a `tapply()` solution around.

```
with(d, tapply(z, list(x, y), sum))
#   a b c
# x 1 2 3
# y 3 3 2
```

**Data**

```
d <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), z = c(1, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

From `tidyr 0.8.3.9000`, a new function called `pivot_wider()` is introduced. It is basically an upgraded version of the previous `spread()` function [(which is, moreover, no longer under active development)](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/reference/pivot_wider.html). From [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html):

> This vignette describes the use of the new pivot_longer() and
>   pivot_wider() functions. Their goal is to improve the usability of
>   gather() and spread(), and incorporate state-of-the-art features found
>   in other packages.
>
> For some time, it’s been obvious that there is something fundamentally
>   wrong with the design of spread() and gather(). Many people don’t find
>   the names intuitive and find it hard to remember which direction
>   corresponds to spreading and which to gathering. It also seems
>   surprisingly hard to remember the arguments to these functions,
>   meaning that many people (including me!) have to consult the
>   documentation every time.

How to use it (using the data from @Aaron):

```
pivot_wider(data = tmp, names_from = y, values_from = z)

  x         a     b     c
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x         1     2     3
2 y         3     3     2
```

Or in a "full" `tidyverse` fashion:

```
tmp %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = y, values_from = z)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyr package from the tidyverse has an excellent function that does this.

Assuming your variables are named v1, v2 and v3, left to right, and you data frame is named dat:

```
dat %>% 
spread(key = v2,
       value = v3)
```

Ta da!

Comment: see the anwer from @Aaron

Comment: Somehow managed to miss the part at the end where he covered spread. Nice catch, thanks.

Comment: tidyverse solutions now moved to the top.