# reshape matrix - multiple columns in one column

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
SNP     G1      G2      G3
marker1 TT      CC      TT
marker2 AA      AA      AA
marker3 TT      TT      TT
```

And I would like it to look like this :

```
SNP     
>marker1    TT  G1
>marker2    AA  G1
>marker3    TT  G1
>marker1    CC  G2
>marker2    AA  G2
>marker3    TT  G2
>marker1    TT  G3
>marker2    AA  G3
>marker3    TT  G3
```

I am using this:

```
        bsp2<- read.table("C:/R/bsp2.csv", header=TRUE) 

       reshape(as.data.frame(bsp2), direction="long", varying = list(colnames(bsp2)
       [2:6]), v.names="G", idvar="SNP")
```

But I am getting the error message "undefined columns selected".
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `bsp2` has only 4 columns, so `colnames(bsp2)[2:6]` generates `"G1" "G2" "G3" NA NA`, which in turn causes the error.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10234734/210673).  Future searchers may also be interested in the reverse; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9617348/210673)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be much easier using `melt` from **reshape2**:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "SNP     G1      G2      G3
marker1 TT      CC      TT
marker2 AA      AA      AA
marker3 TT      TT      TT",header = T,sep = "")

require(reshape2)
melt(dat,id.var = "SNP")

      SNP variable value
1 marker1       G1    TT
2 marker2       G1    AA
3 marker3       G1    TT
4 marker1       G2    CC
5 marker2       G2    AA
6 marker3       G2    TT
7 marker1       G3    TT
8 marker2       G3    AA
9 marker3       G3    TT
```

Answer (score 4):

Here it is with reshape in base though joran is right melt is likely easier.

```
bsp2 <- read.table(text="SNP     G1      G2      G3
marker1 TT      CC      TT
marker2 AA      AA      AA
marker3 TT      TT      TT ", header=TRUE)

bsp2.long <- reshape(bsp2, direction="long", varying = 2:4, v.names="G", 
    timevar="TIME", times=paste0("G", 1:3), idvar="SNP")

rownames(bsp2.long) <- seq_len(nrow(bsp2.long))
bsp2.long
```

Which yields:

```
      SNP TIME  G
1 marker1   G1 TT
2 marker2   G1 AA
3 marker3   G1 TT
4 marker1   G2 CC
5 marker2   G2 AA
6 marker3   G2 TT
7 marker1   G3 TT
8 marker2   G3 AA
9 marker3   G3 TT
```

Note you need R 2,15 for this to work as I used `paste0`.  If you don't have R2.15 and don't want to install it replace that argument with `times=c("G1", "G2", "G3")`.  Also what I called `TIME` was not necessary as R would have called it `time` but I did so to show you have control over that name with `reshape`.

Comment: +1 for reminding me why I've never bothered to really learn how to use `reshape`. Ugh.