# Reshape three column data frame to a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, I have data which looks like this:

```
    5 7 1 
    5 8 2 
    5 9 3 
    6 7 3 
    6 8 3 
    6 9 2
```

where each column is an array (e.g. `x = [5; 5; 5; 6; 6; 6]`).
I want the data to be put in matrix form in the following manner:

```
        7    8    9
    5   1    2    3
    6   3    3    2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What would be A(1,1) if A is your output matrix? NaN? Zero?

Comment: Can you explain the output matrix in more detail?

Comment: The output matrix does not matter whether it is a= [output] or if it is an array a= [5; 6], b= [7; 1; 3] etc. I just need the output so that i can copy and paste onto excel

Comment: And Andrey, it doesn't matter if A(1,1) is 0, I just want to know if this can be done using MATLAB, thanks

Comment: Nearly everything is possible with MATLAB, but I fail to understand what is it that you want to do with your data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix
my question is the exact same as this one, perhaps it would be easier to understand from this question. Instead of using variables in my case I am using numbers. I was wondering if this process can be done on MATLAB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
>> x =[5 7 1
       5 8 2
       5 9 3
       6 7 3
       6 8 3
       6 9 2];
>> rowlabels = unique(x(:,1))
rowlabels =
     5
     6
>> collabels = unique(x(:,2))'
collabels =
     7     8     9
>> data = reshape(x(:,3),numel(collabels),numel(rowlabels))'
data =
     1     2     3
     3     3     2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix 
my question is similar to this one, except instead of using variables, in my case I am using values. Thank you for the input.