# R merge with itself

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Can I merge data like

```
name,#797,"Stachy, Poland"
at_rank,#797,1
to_center,#797,4.70
predicted,#797,4.70
```

According to the second column and take the first column as column names?

```
     name             at_rank to_center predicted
#797 "Stachy, Poland" 1       4.70      4.70
```

Upon request, the whole set of data: http://sprunge.us/cYSJ

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to accomplish this with R (although I'm interested). These types of transitions are very straightforward with [Data Wrangler](http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/). [Google Refine](https://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) may also work.

Comment: @Lenwood data wrangler only supports 1k columns - got 40k

Comment: That's correct for the web version, but you can select script (Python or javaScript) as the output and run DW against any number of files or rows on your own system using their runtime tools.

Comment: This is called reshaping the data from long to wide format.  Here's an answer that collects various ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673

Comment: @AnandaMahto not sure if it's helpful, last 4 lines:  http://sprunge.us/BFeZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, of reading the data in, should not be a problem if your strings with commas are quoted (which they seem to be). Using `read.csv` with the `header=FALSE` argument does the trick with the data you shared. (Of course, if the data file had headers, delete that argument.)

From there, you have several options. Here are two.

1. `reshape` (base R) works fine for this:

   ```
   myDF <- read.csv("http://sprunge.us/cYSJ", header=FALSE)
   myDF2 <- reshape(myDF, direction="wide", idvar="V2", timevar="V1")
   head(myDF2)
   #    V2                V3.name V3.at_rank V3.to_center V3.predicted
   # 1  #1                Kitoman          1         2.41         2.41
   # 5  #2                Hosaena          2         4.23         9.25
   # 9  #3 Vinzelles, Puy-de-Dôme          1         5.20         5.20
   # 13 #4     Whitelee Wind Farm          6         3.29         8.07
   # 17 #5    Steveville, Alberta          1         9.59         9.59
   # 21 #6        Rocher, Ardèche          1         0.13         0.13
   ```
2. The `reshape2` package is also useful in these cases. It has simpler syntax and the output is also a little "cleaner" (at least in terms of variable names).

   ```
   library(reshape2)
   myDFw_2 <- dcast(myDF, V2 ~ V1)
   # Using V3 as value column: use value.var to override.
   head(myDFw_2)
   #       V2 at_rank                                       name predicted to_center
   # 1     #1       1                                    Kitoman      2.41      2.41
   # 2    #10       4                            Icaraí de Minas      6.07      8.19
   # 3   #100       2        Scranton High School (Pennsylvania)      5.78      7.63
   # 4  #1000       1                  Bat & Ball Inn, Clanfield      2.17      2.17
   # 5 #10000       3                                     Tăuteu      1.87      5.87
   # 6 #10001       1 Oak Grove, Northumberland County, Virginia      5.84      5.84
   ```

Comment: +1 beat me by 48 seconds. I was glad to get a chance to use this function, though. the arguments are confusing...

Comment: How can I cast some of the columns? Because they're still of character type.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, `reshape` is notorious for being one of the more confusing functions to use. I've found a lot of datasets need a `time` or `id` variable to be generated before it can be used correctly.

Comment: @Tass, I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the follow-up question. Can you elaborate a bit on what you need? Which columns are of type "character" and what should they be instead?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `reshape` package from Hadley.  If I understand correctly, you are just pivoting your data from long to wide.

Comment: I would be curious how this performs with 40k columns.

Comment: I'm curious how to read it into R because it gets confused because I have strings and numbers in a single column...

Comment: @Tass, so is your question about data manipulation or about reading the data into R?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case all you really need to do is transpose, cast to data.frame, set the colnames to the first row and then remove the first row.  It might be possible to skip the last step through some combination of arguments to data.frame but I don't know what they are right now.