# Transform rows to columns in R for statistical correlation analysis

Tags: r, rows, correlation, reshape

I am attempting to transform columns to rows in R, without the use of reshape (can't install the package). The data I have received includes attributes and their corresponding metrics. I would like to calculate the statistical correlation between all of these attributes--16000 in total with 8 million records. Not all records have the same number of attributes.

To do this, I believe I will have to convert columns to rows so that I can eventually use the cor function e.g. cor(x[,1], x[,2:16000]). This may be wholly unnecessary if there is some way to use the cor function by attribute i.e. correlation between attribute 1 and 2, attribute 1 and 3, attribute 1 ... N. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 ID          Attribute  Metric1 
 [1,]  1         1 -1.6363007
 [2,]  2         1  1.1483294
 [3,]  3         1  2.1682566
 [4,]  4         1 -1.1823649
 [5,]  5         1 -1.3631378
 [6,]  1         2 -1.1715544
 [7,]  2         2  1.5164278
 [8,]  3         2 -1.0110274
 [9,]  4         2 -0.9421652
[10,]  5         2 -0.2105443
[11,]  6         2 -0.4143548
[12,]  7         2 -1.6170975
[13,]  8         2  1.2402303
[14,]  9         2  0.4460047
[15,]  7         3  0.1060407
[16,]  8         3  0.9796893
[17,]  9         3  0.9254911
[18,] 10         3 -1.5728600
[19,] 11         3 -0.8082675
[20,] 12         3 -1.8643084
```

Transformation:

```
ID  attribute1  attribute2  attribute3
1   -1.6363007  -1.1715544  na
2   1.1483294   1.5164278   na
3   2.1682566   -1.0110274  na
4   -1.1823649  -0.9421652  na
5   -1.3631378  -0.2105443  na
6   na          -0.4143548  na
7   na          -1.6170975  0.1060407
8   na           1.2402303  0.9796893
9   na           0.4460047  0.9254911
10  na           na         -1.57286
11  na           na         -0.8082675
12  na           na         -1.8643084


test <- cbind(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,9),rep(3,6)), replicate(1,rnorm(20)))
test <- cbind(c(1:5,1:9,7:12),test)
```

@Aaron

```
q <- matrix(nrow=20,ncol=3)
colnames(q) <- c("x","y","z")
q[,3] <- replicate(1, rnorm(20))
q[,2] <- c(101,102,103,104,105,106, 107, 108, 101,103,107,109, 104,110,102,103,106,109,108,112)
q[15:20,1] <- 10000003
q[9:14,1] <- 10000002
q[1:8,1] <- 10000001
q <- data.frame(q)
q$x <- factor(q$x)
q$y <- factor(q$y)
q$z <- factor(q$z)

with(q, {
  out <- matrix(nrow=nlevels(x), ncol=nlevels(y),
                dimnames=list(levels(x), levels(y)))
  out[cbind(x, y)] <- z
  out
})
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of the starting data using `dput`?

Comment: Also, you won't have any luck with `cor` if there are `NA`s in your resulting dataframe.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, even without the handy `reshape` package; this answer has collected many of them in one place: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673

Comment: @Aaron Per your matrix indexing example, is there a way to include the values for z rather than the indexes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It does put the values of z in the resulting matrix.

Comment: I have included a toy example in the original question box.

Comment: Just don't make `z` a factor.  If you want it numeric, leave it that way.  If you want it a character, use `as.character`.

Comment: Thanks Aaaron! I'm finding the R learning curve to be rather shallow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the "reshape" or "reshape2" packages. Just use base R `reshape()`. Assuming your `data.frame` is named "temp":

```
reshape(temp, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="Attribute")
#       ID Metric1.1  Metric1.2  Metric1.3
# [1,]   1 -1.636301 -1.1715544         NA
# [2,]   2  1.148329  1.5164278         NA
# [3,]   3  2.168257 -1.0110274         NA
# [4,]   4 -1.182365 -0.9421652         NA
# [5,]   5 -1.363138 -0.2105443         NA
# [11,]  6        NA -0.4143548         NA
# [12,]  7        NA -1.6170975  0.1060407
# [13,]  8        NA  1.2402303  0.9796893
# [14,]  9        NA  0.4460047  0.9254911
# [18,] 10        NA         NA -1.5728600
# [19,] 11        NA         NA -0.8082675
# [20,] 12        NA         NA -1.8643084
```

If your data are a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`, you will need to convert it to a `data.frame` before using `reshape()`, or you can use `xtabs()`. However, using `xtabs()` creates zeroes instead of `NA`s. Here's the `xtabs()` approach:

```
xtabs(Metric1 ~ ID + Attribute, tempm)
#     Attribute
# ID            1          2          3
#   1  -1.6363007 -1.1715544  0.0000000
#   2   1.1483294  1.5164278  0.0000000
#   3   2.1682566 -1.0110274  0.0000000
#   4  -1.1823649 -0.9421652  0.0000000
#   5  -1.3631378 -0.2105443  0.0000000
#   6   0.0000000 -0.4143548  0.0000000
#   7   0.0000000 -1.6170975  0.1060407
#   8   0.0000000  1.2402303  0.9796893
#   9   0.0000000  0.4460047  0.9254911
#   10  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.5728600
#   11  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.8082675
#   12  0.0000000  0.0000000 -1.8643084
```

Comment: When I try to implement this line I am prompted with the error message: "Error in match(rval[, idvar], thistime[, idvar]) : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: @user1636475, is your input a `data.frame` or a `matrix`? Try converting it to a `data.frame` before using the example code provided.

Comment: I thought that was the issue, but definitely a matrix.          temp<- cbind(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,9),rep(3,6)), replicate(1,rnorm(20)))
temp <- cbind(c(1:5,1:9,7:12),test)
colnames(temp) <- c("ID", "Attribute", "Metric1")
reshape(temp, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="Attribute")

Comment: @user1636475, as I mentioned, `reshape()` expects a `data.frame`, so try `reshape(data.frame(YOURMATRIXNAME, etc` instead.

Comment: @user1636475, you may want to also start accepting answers to some of your questions. I notice that you've asked four questions on Stack Overflow, but have not marked any of the answers in them as accepted (look for the checkmark next to the answers). Of course, do this only if the answers meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

using `reshape2`

```
  acast(dat, ID~Attribute, value.var="Metric1")
           1          2          3
1  -1.636301 -1.1715544         NA
2   1.148329  1.5164278         NA
3   2.168257 -1.0110274         NA
4  -1.182365 -0.9421652         NA
5  -1.363138 -0.2105443         NA
6         NA -0.4143548         NA
7         NA -1.6170975  0.1060407
8         NA  1.2402303  0.9796893
9         NA  0.4460047  0.9254911
10        NA         NA -1.5728600
11        NA         NA -0.8082675
12        NA         NA -1.8643084
```

Comment: I'm assuming that if they can't install the "reshape" package, they also can't install the "reshape2" package ;)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I assume nothing not existing in the question :)