# Reframing magic on data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am currently learning to work with data.frame and quite confused on how to reorder them.

At the moment, I have a data.frame that shows :

- column 1: a shop name
- column 2: a product
- column 3: the number of purchase for this product by this shop

or visually something like this:

```
+---+-----------+-------+----------+--+
|   | Shop.Name | Items | Product  |  |
+---+-----------+-------+----------+--+
| 1 | Shop1     |     2 | Product1 |  |
| 2 | Shop1     |     4 | Product2 |  |
| 3 | Shop2     |     3 | Product1 |  |
| 4 | Shop3     |     2 | Product1 |  |
| 5 | Shop3     |     1 | Product4 |  |
+---+-----------+-------+----------+--+
```

What I would like to achieve is the following "shop-centric" structure:

- column 1: a shop name
- column 2: Items sold for product1
- column 3: Items sold for product2
- column 4: Items sold for product3
  ...

When there is no line for a specific shop/product (because of no sales), I would like to create a 0.

or

```
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+--+--+
|   | Shop  | Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 | Prod4 | ... |  |  |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+--+--+
| 1 | Shop1 |     2 |     4 |     0 |     0 | ... |  |  |
| 2 | Shop2 |     3 |     0 |     0 |     0 | ... |  |  |
| 3 | Shop3 |     2 |     0 |     0 |     1 | ... |  |  |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+--+--+
```

Comment: Have a look at the function `reshape`, or `dcast` in the **reshape2** package.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673 has a long list of ways to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answers so far work to a certain degree, but don't fully answer your question. In particular, they don't address the issue of a case in which there are no shops which sold a particular product. From your example input and desired output, there were no shops which sold "Product3". Indeed, "Product3" does not even appear in your source `data.frame`. Additionally, they do not address the possible situation of having more than one row for each Shop + Product combination.

Here's a modified version of your data and the two solutions so far. I've added another row for a combination of "Shop1" and "Product1". Notice that I have converted your products to a `factor` variable that includes the levels that the variable can take, even if none of the cases actually has that level.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  Shop.Name = c("Shop1", "Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3", "Shop3", "Shop1"),
  Items = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2),
  Product = factor(
    c("Product1", "Product2", "Product1", "Product1", "Product4", "Product1"),
    levels = c("Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4")))
```

1. `dcast` from "reshape2"

   ```
   library(reshape2)
   dcast(mydf, formula = Shop.Name ~ Product, value="Items", fill=0)
   # Using Product as value column: use value.var to override.
   # Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
   # Error in .fun(.value[i], ...) : 
   #   2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
   ```

   Wha? Suddenly does not work. Do this instead:

   ```
   dcast(mydf, formula = Shop.Name ~ Product, 
         fill = 0, value.var = "Items", 
         fun.aggregate = sum, drop = FALSE)
   #   Shop.Name Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
   # 1     Shop1        4        4        0        0
   # 2     Shop2        3        0        0        0
   # 3     Shop3        2        0        0        1
   ```
2. Let's be oldschool. `cast` from "reshape"

   ```
   library(reshape)
   cast(mydf, formula = Shop.Name ~ Product, value="Items", fill=0)
   # Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
   #   Shop.Name Product1 Product2 Product4
   # 1     Shop1        2        1        0
   # 2     Shop2        1        0        0
   # 3     Shop3        1        0        1
   ```

   Eh. Not what you wanted again... Try this instead:

   ```
   cast(mydf, formula = Shop.Name ~ Product, 
        value = "Items", fill = 0, 
        add.missing = TRUE, fun.aggregate = sum)
   #   Shop.Name Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
   # 1     Shop1        4        4        0        0
   # 2     Shop2        3        0        0        0
   # 3     Shop3        2        0        0        1
   ```
3. Let's get back to basics. `xtabs` from base R

   ```
   xtabs(Items ~ Shop.Name + Product, mydf)
   #          Product
   # Shop.Name Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
   #     Shop1        4        4        0        0
   #     Shop2        3        0        0        0
   #     Shop3        2        0        0        1
   ```

   Or, if you prefer a `data.frame` (note that your "Shop.Name" variable has been converted to the `row.names` of the `data.frame`):

   ```
   as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Items ~ Shop.Name + Product, mydf))
   #       Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
   # Shop1        4        4        0        0
   # Shop2        3        0        0        0
   # Shop3        2        0        0        1
   ```

Comment: This is a bit more comprehensive than the other solutions posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix

Comment: @Anando Mahto, I m dealing with the same issue İf u have time to answer my question I ll be greatfull. in my dataset shopname is userid which is unique and for example I want to see as a first row if userid=5.how can I do that? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `dcast` from the `reshape2` library:

```
library(reshape2)

> df <- data.frame(Shop.Name=rep(c("Shop1","Shop2","Shop3"),each=3),
+                  Items=rpois(9,5),
+                  Product=c(rep(c("Prod1","Prod2","Prod3","Prod4"),2),"Prod5")
+ )
> df
  Shop.Name Items Product
1     Shop1     6   Prod1
2     Shop1     5   Prod2
3     Shop1     6   Prod3
4     Shop2     5   Prod4
5     Shop2     6   Prod1
6     Shop2     6   Prod2
7     Shop3     4   Prod3
8     Shop3     7   Prod4
9     Shop3     5   Prod5
> dcast(df,Shop.Name ~ Product,value.var="Items",fill=0)
  Shop.Name Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 Prod4 Prod5
1     Shop1     6     5     6     0     0
2     Shop2     6     6     0     5     0
3     Shop3     0     0     4     7     5
```

Comment: Not quite. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515736/1270695).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the original reshape package for any reason:

```
Shop.Name <- c("Shop1", "Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3", "Shop3")
Items <- c(2,4,3,2,1)
Product <- c("Product1", "Product2", "Product1", "Product1", "Product4")
(df <- data.frame(Shop.Name, Items, Product))

cast(df, formula = Shop.Name ~ Product, value="Items", fill=0)
```