# R's reshape() function changes column labels

Tags: r, reshape

I want to convert my data from long into wide format. If find it really annoying that `reshape` changes the column labels, is there any way to avoid that?

For example if I would have data in long format like this:

```
Year Name Value
1996 a    1
1997 a    2
1998 b    3
1999 b    4
```

I would use `reshape()` like this

```
reshape(long, timevar = "Year", idvar = "Name", direction = "wide")
```

The conversion itself works fine, but the column names would look like these:

```
Name Time.1996 Time.1997 Time.1998 Time.1999
```

The only thing I can think of right now is to rename the column names manually, which is really annoying if you have to do it for multiple data sets.

Comment: See a collection of various ways to do this reshaping here; perhaps one of them would better fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see a *question* here, but if it bothers you that much, there are a few alternatives.

In base R, you can use `xtabs` (a lot of the time) for this type of conversion.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Value ~ Name + Year, long))
#   1996 1997 1998 1999
# a    1    2    0    0
# b    0    0    3    4
```

Or, resorting to packages, you can use `dcast` from "reshape2".

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(long, Name ~ Year)
# Using Value as value column: use value.var to override.
#   Name 1996 1997 1998 1999
# 1    a    1    2   NA   NA
# 2    b   NA   NA    3    4
```

---

I do agree that with a single variable being reshaped in this manner, it can be annoying to have the names modified the way they are. However, keep in mind other typical use-cases of the `reshape` function, and you'll see it can be quite helpful. For example, let's add another column to your "long" dataset and then reshape:

```
> long$Something <- 5:8
> reshape(long, timevar = "Year", idvar = "Name", direction = "wide")
  Name Value.1996 Something.1996 Value.1997 Something.1997 Value.1998
1    a          1              5          2              6         NA
3    b         NA             NA         NA             NA          3
  Something.1998 Value.1999 Something.1999
1             NA         NA             NA
3              7          4              8
```

Without retaining the name of the column that is being reshaped, you wouldn't know which 1996 is for "Value" and which is for "Something".

---

*Finally*, if you wanted to use `reshape` (which I happen to like), *and* your actual data are accurately reflected by this example (just one column that needs to be "pivoted" by one or more columns), here are two more options:

***Use `setNames`***. *It's easy to predict what the names should be: a vector of your ID variables, followed by the time variable.*

```
> setNames(reshape(long, timevar = "Year", idvar = "Name", direction = "wide"), 
+          c("Name", long$Year))
  Name 1996 1997 1998 1999
1    a    1    2   NA   NA
3    b   NA   NA    3    4
```

***Use `sub` or `gsub` to edit the variable names.*** *Again, since we know we just have one variable that was pivoted, it is easy to predict the change that needs to be made.*

```
> wide <- reshape(long, timevar = "Year", idvar = "Name", direction = "wide")
> names(wide)
[1] "Name"       "Value.1996" "Value.1997" "Value.1998" "Value.1999"
> names(wide) <- gsub("Value.", "", names(wide))
> wide
  Name 1996 1997 1998 1999
1    a    1    2   NA   NA
3    b   NA   NA    3    4
```

Comment: Thanks, `xtabs()` works really great for me and does exactly what I wanted!