# Transposing data with R

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following dataset :

```
prod    month    count
sub12  2012-06  566
sub1    2012-06  10239
sub6    2012-06   524
sub12  2012-07   2360
sub1    2012-07   13853
sub6    2012-07    2352
sub12  2012-08   3950
sub1    2012-08   14738
sub6    2012-08   4104
```

I'm trying to have this :

```
prod    2012-06   2012-07
sub12  566          2360
sub1   10239       13853
sub6   524           2352
```

I've run the following command lines:

```
aperm(table(data))
data.frame(table(data))
```

but I'm getting the wrong results.

Where am I wrong, please?

Comment: You do not want to transpose, you want to reshape/cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for "reshape long wide".

```
data <- read.table(text="prod    month    count
sub12  2012-06  566
sub1    2012-06  10239
sub6    2012-06   524
sub12  2012-07   2360
sub1    2012-07   13853
sub6    2012-07    2352
sub12  2012-08   3950
sub1    2012-08   14738
sub6    2012-08   4104",header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
dcast(prod~month,data=data)
#    prod 2012-06 2012-07 2012-08
# 1  sub1   10239   13853   14738
# 2 sub12     566    2360    3950
# 3  sub6     524    2352    4104
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with base R, you can use `xtabs`:

```
> xtabs(count ~ prod + month, data)
       month
prod    2012-06 2012-07 2012-08
  sub1    10239   13853   14738
  sub12     566    2360    3950
  sub6      524    2352    4104
```

If you prefer a `data.frame` as the output, wrap your `xtabs` with `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(count ~ prod + month, data))
      2012-06 2012-07 2012-08
sub1    10239   13853   14738
sub12     566    2360    3950
sub6      524    2352    4104
```

Comment: Or `reshape(data, direction = "wide", idvar="prod", timevar="month")`.

Comment: @Roland, but then with a comment like that you spoil the fun of having 10 answers to achieve the same thing! Now... [where is Aaron](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/1270695)?