# Reshape three column data to matrix in C++

Tags: c++, performance, file, hash

I have a file containing three columns I want to reshape it to matrix.

This question was answered in this link using R:
[Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix)

Since the input file is too big I want to use C++ for this purpose.

How can I create a matrix in C++ that have a fast access to its element?

After that I can read the big file with three columns line by line and put the value in the right place using hash key or indexing.

I think map form std lib can do it for one dimensional array.

Comment: "How can I create a matrix in C++ that have a fast access to its element?" By using one of the many existing [libraries](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/353)

Comment: I do not want it for matrix algebra I just want to create it!

Comment: You can always make a multidimensional container that uses the `[]` operator.  This page is an excellent starting point to the available containers in C++: [Containers Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).  The `unordered_map` uses hashing if you need constant time element access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you want to do matrix algebra (since you give a link to R I suppose you want to do mathematics with that data) the best is to use a mathematics library. For example if you use [eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) it is very easy to read the matrix. After reading the matrix there are plenty of functions you can apply to these data. (check the benchmarks of this library here http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark) Generally speaking if you want to do linear algebra or vector manipulation the best is to use libraries already used/tested/optimized rather to use you own std::vector<> or std::map<> and write your own loops / functions in order to manipulate the data. Your linear algebra code will not be optimized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
   Eigen::MatrixXd m(2,3) ;
   m << 1, 2, 3,
        3, 3, 2;
   std::cout << m << std::endl ;
   std::cout << "Transpose of matrix:" << std::endl;
   std::cout << m.transpose() << std::endl;

   return 0 ;
}
```

You can compile and run it (in my system the library has been installed to `/usr/local/include/eigen3/`):

```
$ g++ matrix.cpp  -I /usr/local/include/eigen3/ -o matrix
$ ./matrix 
1 2 3
3 3 2
Transpose of matrix:
1 3
2 3
3 2
```

For example if you want to transpose this matrix you can do it easily do it with `m.transpose()` method.