# Converting factor levels to column names

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's assume that I have the following data set (named data set):

```
id  type    count
1   typeA   10
1   typeB   20
1   typeC   30
2   typeA   15
2   typeB   15
3   typeC   20
```

What will be the R code that'll produce the following table:

```
id  type_A  type_B  type_C
1   10       20       30
2   15       15       na
3   na       na       20
```

Comment: That is the most basic reshaping problem and  it could be solved in numerous trivial ways, for instance, 
`library(reshape2) ; dcast(df, id ~ type, value.var = "count")`

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix)

Comment: It doesn't work in this case since it needs an aggregation function (assumes length as a default).

Comment: It works perfectly (tested on your data). If you want some other aggregation function, then just specify it within `dcast`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(dat, type, count)

#   id typeA typeB typeC
# 1  1    10    20    30
# 2  2    15    15    NA
# 3  3    NA    NA    20
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.