# Pivoting a large data set

Tags: r, pivot, pivot-table

I have a csv that looks a bit like this (tabs added for readability):

```
Dimension,    Date,    Metric
A,            Mon,     23
A,            Tues,    25
B,            Mon,     7
B,            Tues,    9
```

I want to run some distance + hclust analysis, which I've done before. But I like (and perhaps need) it in this format:

```
Dimension,    Mon,    Tues
A,            23,     25
B,            7,      9
```

I could do this pretty easily in Excel with a pivot. The problem is I have ~10,000 dimensions and ~1,200 dates - so the source CSV is about 12M rows by 3 columns. I want ~10,000 rows by ~1,200 columns.

Is there a way I can do this transform in R? The logic of a little Python script to do this is simple, but I'm not sure how it'll handle such a large CSV - and I can't imagine this is a new issue. Don't want to reinvent the wheel!

Thanks for any tips :)

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can use the [`fastcluster`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fastcluster/fastcluster.pdf) package which will make the `hclust` part of this analysis much faster.

Comment: What do you want to do when you have duplicated "Dimension" + "Date" combinations? Just sum the values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshape three column data frame to matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or just a `spread`:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, Date, Metric)
  Dimension Mon Tues
1         a  23   25
2         b   7    9
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(spread(df, Date, Metric))
Unit: milliseconds
                     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 spread(df, Date, Metric) 1.461595 1.491919 1.628366 1.566753 1.635374 2.606135   100
 microbenchmark(suppressMessages(dcast(dt, Dimension~Date)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 suppressMessages(dcast(dt, Dimension ~ Date)) 3.365726 3.416384 3.770659 3.471678 4.011316 7.235719   100

microbenchmark(suppressMessages(dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension~Date)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                 expr      min      lq   

mean   median       uq
 suppressMessages(dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension ~ Date)) 2.375445 2.52218 2.7684 2.614706 2.703075
      max neval
 15.96149   100
```

and here data table without `sppressMessages`

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                   expr      min       lq     mean median       uq     max neval
 dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension ~ Date) 2.667337 3.428127 4.749301 4.0476 5.289618 14.3823   100
```

and here data table does not have to guess:

```
 microbenchmark(dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension ~ Date, value.var = "Metric"))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                         expr      min       lq    mean   median
 dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension ~ Date, value.var = "Metric") 2.077276 2.118707 2.28623 2.168667
       uq      max neval
 2.320579 5.780479   100
```

Comment: Using same function now, I'm trying to use blanks instead of NA with `fill = ""`, but I still get NA for missing values. Suggestions?

Comment: with this data set or another one?

Comment: Tried both this one and own

Comment: I do not know, with this data there are no problem with NA (there aren't NAs). I can't figure out your problem. Maybe you could try `fill = " "` , Note the space!

Comment: To OC - sorry for flooding your thread. I used "Wed" instead of one "Tue" in this dataset

Comment: I really hope you're not posting benchmarking results for 4 rows of sample data. `dcast.data.table` is likely to be noticeably faster than `spread`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I know it should but just for curiosity I am doing other tests and it is alway slower! I admit I have no knowledge of `data.table` but am i missing something?

Comment: Why are you using `suppressMessages`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have updated. I repeat that maybe I am missing something (very probable due to my ignorance of `data.table`) but it looks slower!

Comment: @AnandaMahto to avoid 100 `Using 'Metric' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override` messages.

Comment: @SabDeM, just change the code according to the message :-) `dcast.data.table(dt, Dimension ~ Date, value.var = "Metric")` should get rid of the message if that's what your'e getting.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I have posted some benchmarks. I have no idea why it is slower anyway... I think it's a matter for you power users :)

Comment: @SabDeM, in case you're interested: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/3722c8ca442d9249b491

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(Dimension=rep(letters[1:2], each=2), Date=c('Mon','Tues'), Metric=c(23,25,7,9))

dcast(dt, Dimension~Date)
#  Dimension Mon Tues
#1         a  23   25
#2         b   7    9
```

Comment: And converting it to `data.table` before reshape could be great for that large data