# Reshape columns into multiple columns using a column as key

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a data set with three columns
The first column includes variable names, the second column include time stamps, and the third column is the value
For example

```
var1, 2015-1-1, 20
var1, 2015-1-2, 30
var2, 2015-1-1, 40
var2, 2015-1-2, 50
```

I'd like to convert the data set from this format to a format with the first column of time stamp, and the rest columns for each variable value. Can anyone provide a hint using R data.table or reshape package?
For example:

```
2015-1-1, 20, 40
2015-1-2, 30, 50
```

Comment: Try `library(reshape2);dcast(df1, V2~V1, value.var='V3')` where `V1:V3` are the column names in the dataset `df1`

Comment: `data.table` also has a `dcast` method so @akruns code will work with `dcast.data.table(setDT(df1)...` if you want it in a `data.table` way.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix) is also a good reference,

Comment: Thanks a lot. These work great. data.table is awesome and very fast.