# Reshape a data frame to matrix from text file value.var errors

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, reshape2

I have a problem very similar to the one here: [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix)

Except I am taking data from a text file, and I'm trying to use the `reshape2` library and `dcast` method

here is my text file:

```
'Group','LiteracyLevel','Frequency'
'Shifting','Illerate',114
'Shifting','Primary',10
'Shifting','AtLeastMiddle',45
'Settled','Illerate',76
'Settled','Primary',2
'Settled','AtLeastMiddle',53
'Town','Illerate',93
'Town','Primary',13
'Town','AtLeastMiddle',208
```

it should be changed to this format, because i want to use `barplot(as.matrix(data))` on it.

```
'Group','Illerate','Primary','AtLeastMiddle'
'Shifting',114,10,45
'Settled',76,2,53
'Town',93,13,208
```

I don't know what to enter for the value.var part of dcast.  I'm assuming it's frequency.  My current attempts to reshape the data look like this:

```
> data <- read.csv("ex3-39.txt", header=TRUE)

> dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var="X.Frequency")
Error: value.var (X.Frequency) not found in input

> dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var="Frequency")
Error: value.var (Frequency) not found in input

> dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var="data$X.Frequency")
Error: value.var (data$X.Frequency) not found in input

> dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var=data$X.Frequency)
Error: value.var (1141045762539313208) not found in input
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var=Frequency)
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'Frequency' not found
```

Comment: Maybe your data doesn't look like you expect it to look like (please provide the output of `dput(data)`) And if you have a dataframe in dcast, you can just use the column names in your call to decast. `dcast(data, Group~LiteracyLevel, value.var="Frequency")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this helps

```
library(reshape2)
data<-read.csv("filename.csv",quote = "'")
dcast(data, data$Group~data$LiteracyLevel, value.var="Frequency")
```

this gives output as

```
  data$Group AtLeastMiddle Illerate Primary
1    Settled            53       76       2
2   Shifting            45      114      10
3       Town           208       93      13
```

I think you have missed `quote="'"` parameter and your column names are of the form

```
"X.Group." "X.LiteracyLevel." "X.Frequency."
```

If you dont want to use `quote="'"` param use:

```
dcast(data, data$X.Group.~data$X.LiteracyLevel., value.var="X.Frequency.")
```

this will give output

```
  data$X.Group. 'AtLeastMiddle' 'Illerate' 'Primary'
1     'Settled'              53         76         2
2    'Shifting'              45        114        10
3        'Town'             208         93        13
```

This is for fun. To create a nice barplot after this code dont cast the whole matrix. You should leave the first column as legend

Let `final_data` contains the reshaped data. For matrix skip the first column and use that as a legend.

```
barplot(as.matrix(final_data[,2:4]),legend=final_data$"data$Group")
```

This will give a nice graph as

[image]

Comment: I am using barplot(as.matrix(final_data[,2:4]),legend=final_data$"data$Group") but the graph that is produced does not display a legend for me.

Comment: but rest of the graph is same as mine?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the graph is as yours.

Comment: try using custom legend and see if this works. This will clarify if something is wrong with data or plotting.
`barplot(as.matrix(final_data[,2:4]),legend=c("Settled","Shifting","Town"))`

Comment: The custom legend works!   Why did the custom legend work while the first legend didn't?

Comment: Can you also see the result of command `str(final_data)` and ensure `data$Group` column is factor and displays something like this `Factor w/ 3 levels "Settled","Shifting",..: 1 2 3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89018/discussion-between-dhawal-kapil-and-armorcode).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Just to make sure we're dealing with the same data...
df <- read.csv(quote="'",text="'Group','LiteracyLevel','Frequency'
'Shifting','Illerate',114
'Shifting','Primary',10
'Shifting','AtLeastMiddle',45
'Settled','Illerate',76
'Settled','Primary',2
'Settled','AtLeastMiddle',53
'Town','Illerate',93
'Town','Primary',13
'Town','AtLeastMiddle',208")
df
#                     Group LiteracyLevel Frequency
# 1                Shifting      Illerate       114
# 2                Shifting       Primary        10
# 3                Shifting AtLeastMiddle        45
# 4                 Settled      Illerate        76
# 5                 Settled       Primary         2
# 6                 Settled AtLeastMiddle        53
# 7                    Town      Illerate        93
# 8                    Town       Primary        13
# 9                    Town AtLeastMiddle       208

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Group~LiteracyLevel)
#                     Group AtLeastMiddle Illerate Primary
# 1                 Settled            53       76       2
# 2                Shifting            45       NA      NA
# 3                    Town           208       93      13
# 4                Shifting            NA      114      10
```

The problem is that you need to specify *column names* in the formula (referenced to `data`), not columns. When you specify a column like you did, e.g. `df$Group` the resulting vector is *unnamed*.

```
names(df)
# [1] "Group"         "LiteracyLevel" "Frequency"    
names(df$Group)
# NULL
```