# R - Build adjacency matrix from values in one column and their co-membership to values in second column

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a","b","c"), y=c("p","q","p"))
df
  x y
1 a p
2 b q
3 c p
```

How do I create a matrix out of column `x` reflecting co-membership to values in column `y`? In the data frame above, `a` and `c` share value `p`, so in the resulting adjacency matrix, I want their intersecting cell to have value `1`, which stands for "co-affiliated" as opposed to `0` meaning "not co-affiliated".

The desired output looks like this:

```
                  a b c
                a 0 0 1
                b 0 0 0
                c 1 0 0
```

*[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355892/build-a-square-adjacency-matrix-from-data-frame-or-data-table) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format) questions are similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: `tcrossprod(table(df))`, (then set `diag` to zero)

Comment: can you post it as answer?

Comment: NBK ; what do yo think: mark https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977596/how-do-i-calculate-the-co-occurrence-in-the-table as a duplicate?

Comment: similar, but not sure if duplicate, especially considering how the question is put...

Comment: yes absolutely they are phrased differently -- by marking this as a duplicate it means if some uses similar words as you have used they will still be directed to the other answer

Comment: Yes, makes sense

Comment: good stuff. done