# How can I reshape a dataframe in R using dcast (advanced)?

Tags: r

I have the following R dataframe

```
df1=data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), y = c("f","g","g","h","i","f"), z=c(6,7,5,2,1,5))  

      x y z
    1 1 f 6
    2 1 g 7
    3 2 g 5
    4 2 h 2
    5 2 i 1
    6 3 f 5
```

and I need to obtain

```
df2=data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), f=c(6,0,5), g=c(7,5,0), h=c(0,2,0),i=c(0,1,0))  

      x f g h i
    1 1 6 7 0 0
    2 2 0 5 2 1
    3 3 5 0 0 0
```

I tried using dcast from reshape2

```
df3=dcast(df1,x~y,length)
```

which yields

```
  x f g h i
1 1 1 1 0 0
2 2 0 1 1 1
3 3 1 0 0 0
```

which is not exactly what I need.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I realize this question was already asked and a complete answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix).

By the way Akrun's answer is exactly what I need in a clear format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to specify the `fun.aggregate` if the values in the 'z' column needs to be populated for each combination of 'x' and 'y' (assuming that there are no duplicate combinations for 'x' and 'y'

```
dcast(df1, x~y, value.var='z', fill=0)
#  x f g h i
#1 1 6 7 0 0
#2 2 0 5 2 1
#3 3 5 0 0 0
```

---

Or using `spread` from `library(tidyr)`

```
spread(df1, y, z, fill=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. +1 for "fill=0"

Comment: I did, I'm waiting to reach 15 points to have my vote published.