# Making a barplot in R/ Chi squared test on data

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart, chi-squared

hello I am not good at statistics at all, and have this set of data which I keep getting errors for when trying to make a barplot to compare the counts of 5 different behaviours over 9 different days. How can I possibly do this in R, and how can I do a chi-squared test to check if there is a statistical difference between the different behavioural categories of their counts?
This is my dataset:
    [an image of my dataset as it was too large to paste here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g0iO.png)

Comment: There's lots of resources out there - http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence - for χ-squared and previous questions like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135900/r-create-barplot-from-aggregated-data-frame - for dealing with barplotting aggregate data.

Comment: `chisq.test()`.