# R: How To Manipulate CSV Database

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataset

I'm very new to R and in researching online and consulting my textbooks, I couldn't quite come up with an answer to this question.

So I have a census survey dataset broken down by Congressional district that I have uploaded into R.  However, for my purposes, I need each observation be one Congressional district with each demographic data point appearing as a variable.  So rather than Alabama's 1st district appearing 100 times for each datapoint in Column E, for instance - I want it to appear once with each of those datapoints in Column E becoming variables as columns.  I also need a a way to make this apply to the other 434 Districts in the dataset.

Here is a rough schematic of what it looks like:

CD |      VARIABLE |          DATA |

AL-1 |     Black population |  100,000 |

AL-1  |   White population |  200,000 |

AL-1  |   Married population 75,000 |

I would like it to look like this:

CD |  BLACK POPULATION | WHITE POPULATION | MARRIED POPULATION |

AL-1 | 100,000 | 200,000 | 75,000 |

Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or good learning resources you could point me to?

Comment: `tidyr::spread`, `data.table::dcast`, `reshape2::dcast`, `stats::reshape`, I could probably go on if I started looking harder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the reshape function.  Lots of options out there as joran points out.

```
DF.long<-data.frame(state = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=3), type =c("XX","YY","ZZ"), value = rnorm(12))
DF.long

DF.wide<-reshape(DF.long,timevar = "type",idvar="state",direction="wide")
DF.wide
```

Comment: I see we're not flagging duplicates anymore

Comment: It was an excuse to look into this since I don't work with R all that much I figured I might as well post it. [Another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix) here that gives a much more complete answer is here which has a pretty good write up.