# How do I get all entrys of a matrix with the same value in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix Q_hyda with 2 columns and n rows:

```
       [1]     [2]
[1]   1950    0.265
[2]   1950    0.176
[3]   1950    0.873
 .     ...     ...
[60]  1951   0.534
[61]  1951   0.142
 .     .        .
 .     .        .
 .     .        .
 .     .        .
[n]   2014    0.152
```

What I want to get is a matrix mat_HQa of this type:

```
      [1950]    [1951]    [1952] ... [2014]
[1]   0.265     0.534      ...       0.152
[2]   0.176     0.142      ...         ...
[3]   0.873      ...       ...         ...
 .     ...       ...       ...         ...
 .     ...       ...       ...         ...
 .     ...       ...       ...         ...
[n]    ...       ...       ...         ...
```

I tried it with some loops:

```
## Create a matrix mat_HQa with a_n columns (where a_n is the number of different years) and 366 rows

mat_HQa = matrix(0, 366, a_n)
colnames(mat_HQa)=as.vector(R_a) # the vector R_a is a timeline from 1950 to 2014

# fill matrix

for (i in 1:a_n)
  {for (j in 1:n) 
      {if (R_a[i] == Q_hyda[j,1]){mat_HQa[j,i] = Q_hyda[j,2]}}}
```

It works for the first column but when it moves to the second column it continues to fill the matrix mat_HQa at the j's position, and I can't figure out how to start at each column at the top.

I'm very new to programming, since it's not my subject.
How can I achieve this? I sure think there's a much easier way to do this.
I'm deeply grateful for any advice.

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB? I'm going to remove the tag since it seems irrelevant

Comment: I'm sorry, if it's wrong. It was a suggested tag and since R and MATLAB are related I thought 'Why not?'.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix) should be helpful; here, something like `xtabs(Q_hyda[, 2] ~ seq_len(nrow(Q_hyda)) + Q_hyda[, 1])`

Comment: If I do so I get this error message: Error in matrix(Q_hyda[, 2], nrows = 65) : unused argument (nrows = 65)

Comment: Do `?matrix` and you will notice the argument is `nrow` and not `nrows`. :)

Comment: I would convert the matrix into a data frame and use spread from the tidyr package or use the reshape2 package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make up the data.

```
col1 <- rep(1950:2014, each = 59)
col2 <- runif(length(col1))
Q_hyda <- cbind(col1, col2)
```

That has colnames but it is a matrix. Let's try the suggested solutions
in order. First up, @ZheyuanLi

```
mat_HQa <-  matrix(Q_hyda[, 2], ncol = 65); colnames(mat_HQa) <- 1950:2014
dim(mat_HQa)

## [1] 59 65

mat_HQa[1:5,1:3]

##           1950      1951       1952
## [1,] 0.5227552 0.3105570 0.33501591
## [2,] 0.4236526 0.7158999 0.04454956
## [3,] 0.8187411 0.1406177 0.02497711
## [4,] 0.5537462 0.6366948 0.92567469
## [5,] 0.2602161 0.7634615 0.85745645
```

This works, although it assumes you have identical numbers of
observations per year. It's nice and direct, and doesn't have to convert
to a data.frame.

Next is the suggestion of @alexis_laz to use `xtabs()`

```
mat_HQa <- xtabs(Q_hyda[, 2] ~ seq_len(nrow(Q_hyda)) + Q_hyda[, 1])
dim(mat_HQa)

## [1] 3835   65

mat_HQa[1:5,1:3]

##                      Q_hyda[, 1]
## seq_len(nrow(Q_hyda))      1950      1951      1952
##                     1 0.5227552 0.0000000 0.0000000
##                     2 0.4236526 0.0000000 0.0000000
##                     3 0.8187411 0.0000000 0.0000000
##                     4 0.5537462 0.0000000 0.0000000
##                     5 0.2602161 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

This is not the right answer. To make this work we need a 3rd variable
that identifies which row the result should go in.

```
Q_hyda <- cbind(Q_hyda, rep(1:59, times = 65))
mat_HQa <- xtabs(Q_hyda[, 2] ~ Q_hyda[,3] + Q_hyda[, 1])
dim(mat_HQa)

## [1] 59 65

mat_HQa[1:5,1:3]

##            Q_hyda[, 1]
## Q_hyda[, 3]       1950       1951       1952
##           1 0.52275520 0.31055703 0.33501591
##           2 0.42365262 0.71589995 0.04454956
##           3 0.81874106 0.14061770 0.02497711
##           4 0.55374618 0.63669482 0.92567469
##           5 0.26021608 0.76346147 0.85745645
```

This is also what we want, but now it is class xtabs which inherits from
table not matrix. We can coerce it back to a matrix but have to remember
to do that!

```
mat_HQa <- as.matrix(mat_HQa)
mat_HQa[1:5, 1:3] # looks fine

##            Q_hyda[, 1]
## Q_hyda[, 3]       1950       1951       1952
##           1 0.52275520 0.31055703 0.33501591
##           2 0.42365262 0.71589995 0.04454956
##           3 0.81874106 0.14061770 0.02497711
##           4 0.55374618 0.63669482 0.92567469
##           5 0.26021608 0.76346147 0.85745645

class(mat_HQa) # still not a matrix!

## [1] "xtabs" "table"
```

Or maybe we can't. So not that impressed with that solution. Probably not having a matrix
is no worry, but you never know.

Once we've added that extra column the problem is now in the form from
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9617348/1480928), and all the
solutions there would apply once you convert to a data.frame. That
includes the answers using reshape2 or tidyr suggested by @Dave2e.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way using `reshape2`, which involves first putting your matrix into a data.frame:

```
Q_hyda <- matrix(c(1950, 1950, 1950, 1951, 1951, 2014,
                .265, .176, .873, .534, .142, .152),
              ncol = 2)
df <- as.data.frame(Q_hyda)
names(df) <- c("year", "val")
# give them an ID within year
df$obs <- unlist(sapply(table(df$year), function(n) 1:n), use.names = FALSE)
df
#   year   val obs
# 1 1950 0.265   1
# 2 1950 0.176   2
# 3 1950 0.873   3
# 4 1951 0.534   1
# 5 1951 0.142   2
# 6 2014 0.152   1
```

Now we apply reshape2:

```
require(reshape2)
dfm <- melt(df, id.vars = c("obs", "year"), value.name = "val")
dfc <- dcast(dfm, obs ~ year, mean, value.var = "val")
dfc
#   obs  1950  1951  2014
# 1   1 0.265 0.534 0.152
# 2   2 0.176 0.142   NaN
# 3   3 0.873   NaN   NaN
```

This is a better object class than a matrix, for subsequent manipulation, but if you really want a matrix, you can coerce it to one using:

```
mat_HQa <- as.matrix(dfc[, -1])
mat_HQa
#       1950  1951  2014
# [1,] 0.265 0.534 0.152
# [2,] 0.176 0.142   NaN
# [3,] 0.873   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the 'tidyr' package:

```
> col1 <- rep(1950:2014, each = 59)
> col2 <- runif(length(col1))
> # add 'sample' as first column for the new row name
> Q_hyda <- data.frame(sample = 1:59, year = col1, value = col2)
> library(tidyr)  # does it all for you
> 
> new_data <- spread(Q_hyda, year, value)
> 
> # small sample of data
> new_data[1:6, 1:4]
  sample       1950       1951       1952
1      1 0.59867896 0.68813505 0.06603773
2      2 0.94072166 0.04474356 0.04468876
3      3 0.78878882 0.55344089 0.40102737
4      4 0.01339499 0.54489195 0.11938488
5      5 0.49914844 0.18922653 0.52316301
6      6 0.49786329 0.79751386 0.95561927
> 
> View(new_data)
```