# Expand unblanced data.frame of values relating two ID variables to balanced matrix

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, outer-join, reshape2

Consider `data.frame` consisting of two ID variables and a third variable, `relate`, indicating the relationship (e.g. a covariance) between each pair of ID variables:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, digits = 2)
set.seed(1)
(example <- data.frame(v1 = LETTERS[rep(c(2,3,1,4,7),
                                       times = c(3,2,2,1,2))],
                      v2 = LETTERS[c(2:4, 4:5, 4:5, 5,8,9)],
                      relate = rnorm(10)))

   v1 v2 relate
1   B  B  -0.63
2   B  C   0.18
3   B  D  -0.84
4   C  D   1.60
5   C  E   0.33
6   A  D  -0.82
7   A  E   0.49
8   D  E   0.74
9   G  H   0.58
10  G  I  -0.31
```

These data are **unbalanced** in that not every pairwise relationship is accounted for and not every in `v1` is in `v2` and vice versa.

The goal is to expand these data into a symmetric matrix where all the unique values in both `v1` and `v2` comprise the row and column names and the entries are the corresponding values of `relate` (if it exists, else `NA`). In other words, to populate the below matrix with values of `relate`:

```
vars <- with(example, unique(c(v1, v2)))
matrix(nrow = length(vars),
       ncol = length(vars),
       dimnames = list(vars, vars))
   B  C  A  D  G  E  H  I
B NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
C NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
A NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
D NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
G NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
E NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
H NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
I NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

However, the ready made solutions I've tried so far (`data.table::dcast`, `reshape2:dcast`) produce the following *unbalanced* results:

```
 data.table::dcast(example, v1~v2, value.var = 'relate')
  v1     B    C     D    E    H     I
1  A    NA   NA -0.82 0.49   NA    NA
2  B -0.63 0.18 -0.84   NA   NA    NA
3  C    NA   NA  1.60 0.33   NA    NA
4  D    NA   NA    NA 0.74   NA    NA
5  G    NA   NA    NA   NA 0.58 -0.31
```

**Is there an efficient way to instead obtain a *balanced*, *symmetric* matrix of values from a set of ID-pairs and relating values?**

One solution that occurs to me is to manually populate the above symmetric matrix of `NA` values using `mapply` and defining a subsetting function, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: Since you, already, allocated a "matrix" -say `mat`-, you can use `mat[as.matrix(example[1:2])] = example$relate`

Comment: @alexis_laz very elegant--care to expand to an answer?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 2):

We can convert the 'v1/v2' columns to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements in the `unlist`ed 'v1/v2' columns in 'example', and then do `dcast` with `drop=FALSE`

```
library(data.table)
un1 <- unique(unlist(example[1:2]))
setDT(example)[, paste0("v", 1:2) := lapply(.SD, factor, levels = un1), 
            .SDcols = v1:v2]
dcast(example, v1~v2, value.var = "relate", drop = FALSE)
#   v1     B    C  A     D  G    E    H     I
#1:  B -0.63 0.18 NA -0.84 NA   NA   NA    NA
#2:  C    NA   NA NA  1.60 NA 0.33   NA    NA
#3:  A    NA   NA NA -0.82 NA 0.49   NA    NA
#4:  D    NA   NA NA    NA NA 0.74   NA    NA
#5:  G    NA   NA NA    NA NA   NA 0.58 -0.31
#6:  E    NA   NA NA    NA NA   NA   NA    NA
#7:  H    NA   NA NA    NA NA   NA   NA    NA
#8:  I    NA   NA NA    NA NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for--had tried specifying `drop = FALSE` but it hadn't occurred to specify additional factor levels. Cheers.