# Reshape data by hour vs day, with value of a third column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, dcast

I'm trying to do some reshaping of hourly climatic data, but I can't get it right...
Here is the data, one day varible (365 levels.+/- 1 depending year), one hour variable (24 levels), one numeric temperature (+/- 8760 obs).

```
head(df)
####         .day .hour temperature
#### 2 2013-01-01     1          19
#### 3 2013-01-01     2          19
#### 4 2013-01-01     3          18
#### 5 2013-01-01     4          18
```

My expected output is a data.frame like this, but instead of the values one (the lenghts) I need the temperature values inside...

```
        .day 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
1 2013-01-01 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2 2013-01-02 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3 2013-01-03 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
4 2013-01-04 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

This output is generated with `dcast(.day~.hour)`, Il also tried some `tidyr` with no success. How can I do this? And what about if there are some missing lines somewhere (a day missing, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do is reformat long data to wide format. `tidyr` has the relevant function `spread` which is appropriate for this purpose. The help files has sufficient example here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/tidyr.pdf#page.14

Comment: @Frash ok now i get this error with `spread`: *Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2138, 2161), (7178, 7179)*. i try to solve it then i let you know if it works

Comment: ok that's probably because of the hour change twice a year.

Comment: @Frash ok now it works fine! thanks a lot. you can post as answer if you want;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reformat data from long to wide format, we can use `tidyr` has the relevant function `spread`. The help files has sufficient example here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/tidyr.pdf#page.14

```
require(tidyr)
spread(df, .hour, temperature, fill = NA) #fill any missing data with NA
```

A comprehensive tour of other options available to effect the same changes is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/2724299