# Optimizing too long loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I'm quite new to R and really really need your help with my double for-loop which takes too much time to complete.

`data` a data table with 659322 rows and 3 columns (ID, Game, Amount)

Each ID is repeated several times (i.e. several Game for each ID), but unevenly distributed across the rows. We may have 2 Games for ID1 (so ID1 appears in 2 rows), 5 Games for ID2, 4 Games for ID3, etc.

I want to create a matrix `datmat` from `data` with:
- Nb of rows = nb of unique values of ID (nb_row=46028)
- Nb of columns = nb of unique values of Game (nb_col=30)
and fill in `datmat` with the corresponding Amount values

Here's what I tried

```
ID <- unique(data$ID)
Game <- unique(data$Game)
nb_row <- length(ID)
nb_col <- length(Game)

datmat <- matrix(c(0),nb_row,nb_col,dimnames=list(NULL,Game))
for(i in 1:nb_row){
  for(j in 1:nb_col){
      datmat[i,j] <- data$Amount[data$ID==ID[i] & data$Game==Game[j]]
  }
}
dt <- data.table(ID,datmat)
```

Any suggestion could be greatly appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: See, also, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: Thanks a lot! `reshape` works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the reshape function :

```
newdata<-reshape(data,timevar="Game",idvar="ID",direction="wide")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! `reshape` is great, though I need to rearrange the data frame a bit but still great!