# Transform multiple rows of a data frame into one row with multiple columns with R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, pivot

I have a data frame with four columns :

```
df=data.frame( UserId=c(1,2,2,2,3,3), CatoId=c('C','A','B','C','D','E'), No=c(1,9,2,2,5,3))  

UserId CatoId No  
1       C     1  
2       A     9  
2       B     2  
2       C     2  
3       D     5  
3       E     3
```

I would like to transform the structure into the following one :

```
UserId A B C D E  
  1    0 0 1 0 0  
  2    9 2 2 0 0 
  3    0 0 0 5 3
```

Where the columns represents all possible values in `CatoId`.
The first data frame has 2 million rows and `CatoId` has 21 different values. So I don't want to use any loops. Is there a way to do this with R. Otherwise what is the best way to proceed?
My goal would be to apply a clustering algorithm on the last dataframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `dcast`:

```
df1 <- dcast(df, UserId ~ CatoId, value.var = "No", fill = 0)
```