# Grouping with numeric variables

Tags: r

I hava a dataframe like this:

```
name, value
stockA,Google
stockA,Yahoo
stockB,NA
stockC,Google
```

I would like to convert the values of rows of the second column to columns and keep the first one and in other have a numeric value to 0 and 1 if not exist or exist the value. Here an example of the expected output:

```
name,Google,Yahoo
stockA,1,1
stockB,0,0
stockC,1,0
```

I tried this:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(melt(df, 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), df + name ~ value, length)
```

and the error it gives me is this:

```
Using value as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i) : undefined columns selected
```

Any idea for the error?

An example in which the previous code works.
Data (df):

```
name,nam2,value
stockA,sth1,Yahoo
stockA,sth2,NA
stockB,sth3,Google
```

and this works:

```
df2 <- dcast(melt(df, 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), name + nam2 ~ value, length)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format) `df <- data.frame(name = c("stockA", "stockA", "stockB", "stockC"),
                 value = c("Google", "Yahoo", NA, "Google")); xtabs(~name+value, data=df)`

Comment: @jogo it works but the first column has an NA with zero and one and the column name doesn't exist

Comment: Please use `dput()` to present your data or give a definition of your dataframe, i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42937389/edit With the dataframe the I used in my comment I got the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has asked to get an explanation for the error caused by

```
dcast(melt(df, 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), df + name ~ value, length)
```

(I'm quite astonished that no one so far has tried to improve the OP's `reshape2` approach to return exactly the expected answer).

There are several issues with OP's code:

1. `df` appears in the `dcast()` formula.
2. The second parameter to `melt()` is `1:2` which means that *all* columns are used as `id.vars`. It should read `1`.
3. But the most crucial point is that the data.frame  `df` already is in *long* format and doesn't need to be reshaped.

So, `df` can be used directly in `dcast()`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df[!is.na(df$value), ], name ~ value, length, drop = FALSE)
#    name Google Yahoo
#1 stockA      1     1
#2 stockB      0     0
#3 stockC      1     0
```

In order to avoid a third `NA` column appearing in the result, the `NA` rows have to be filtered out of `df` before reshaping. On the other hand, `drop = FALSE` is required to ensure `stockB` is included in the result.

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("stockA", "stockA", "stockB", "stockC"), 
                 value = c("Google", "Yahoo", NA, "Google"))
df
#    name  value
#1 stockA Google
#2 stockA  Yahoo
#3 stockB   <NA>
#4 stockC Google
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `spread` from the `tidyr` package.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("stockA", "stockA", "stockB", "stockC"),
                 value = c("Google", "Yahoo", NA, "Google"))
df$row <- 1
df %>% 
  spread(value, row, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-`<NA>`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df2 <- dcast(melt(df, 1:2, na.rm = TRUE), name ~ value, length)`

Just remove `df +` from the equation.

Though this will give you an extra column for NA values, which makes me think the `na.rm` argument isn't working properly in your formulation.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but I receive Using value as value column: use value.var to override.`

Comment: My data look like this: `df <- data.frame(name=c('stockA','stockA','stockB','stockC'),value=c('Google','Yahoo',NA,'Google'))' but I'm not sure what format yours are because you have the values separated by commas.

Comment: It is from my csv. It is a dataframe

Comment: length it is not a column

Comment: I just upvoted the other answer. It does what you need, but you must first install tidyr

Comment: @Patrick Williams There are some more issues with OP's code besides the misplaced `df +`. Another point is that both columns (`1:2`) are used as `id.vars` which perhaps is causing the issue with `no.rm` not being honored. Finally, `melt()` isn't required at all because `df` already is in long format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also with base R:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=',', text=
'name, value
stockA,Google
stockA,Yahoo
stockB,NA
stockC,Google')
xtabs(~., data=df)
#        value
#name     Google Yahoo
#  stockA      1     1
#  stockB      0     0
#  stockC      1     0
```