# Reshape from long to wide according to the number of occurrence of one variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
df1<-structure(list(person = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c"), visitID = c(123, 123, 256, 816, 237, 828, 828, 911), v1 = c(10, 
5, 15, 8, 95, 41, 31, 16), v2 = c(8, 72, 29, 12, 70, 23, 28, 
66), v3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Where person is the name/id of the person and `visitID` is a number generated for each visit. Now each visit may have one or multiple variables (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`). My problem is that I'm trying to transform the structure where cases are aggregated into unique row with wide visits and variables, to look like:

```
df2<-structure(list(person = c("a", "b", "c"), visit1 = c(123, 237, 
911), visit2 = c(256, 828, NA), visit3 = c(816, NA, NA), v1.visit1 = c("10,5", 
"95", "16"), v1.visit2 = c("15", "41,31", NA), v1.visit3 = c("8", 
NA, NA), v2.visit1 = c("8,72", "70", "66"), v2.visit2 = c("29", 
"23,28", NA), v1.visit3 = c("12", NA, NA), v3.visit1 = c("0,1", 
"1", "1"), v3.visit2 = c("0", "1,0", NA), v3.visit3 = c("0", 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Methods I have tried so far:
Method1:
1-aggregate according to "person" with all other variables separated by comma
2-split the variables into multiple columns
The problem with this method is that I would not know then which variable corresponds to which visit, especially that some may have multiple entries and some may not.

Method2:
1-Count number of each `visitID`. Take the maximum number of visits per unique person (in the case above is 3)

2-Create 3 columns for each variable.
didn't know how to proceed from here

I found a great answer in the thread [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format)
so tried working around with reshape and pivot_wider but couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas are appreciated even if did not lead to the same output.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(person, visitID) %>% 
  summarise(across(matches("v[0-9]+"), list)) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  mutate(visit = seq_len(n()) %>% str_c("visit.", .)) %>%  
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = person, 
    names_from = visit, 
    values_from = c("visitID", matches("v[0-9]+"))
  )
```

replace `list` with `~str_c(.x, collapse = ",")` if you want to have it in character style.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into a similar question and found this quicker solution from the data.table package dcast.data.table {data.table}

```
matrix_df <- dcast(df1, visit ~ person, fun.aggregate = length)
```