# r - How to reshape data from long to wide format (when you have messy data, many columns, and want to retain some of the original structure)

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a dataset that I want to convert from long to wide format. I have checked the two most popular answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format)), but I can't make sense of them as they apply to my data structure.

I want to retain the structure of the dataset but tranform the data in the `Code` and `Rating` columns and send them to their own columns to the right of the dataset. The labels in the `Code` column should become their own columns (ignoring blanks), and the data in each column should be poplulated with the values (including `NA`s) from the `Rating` column. The structure should look like this:

```
"ID_Study"
"ID_Person"
"ID_Project"
"Category"
"Orig"
"Cur"
"Nonc"
"Logi"
"Impa"
"OTHB"
"T&E"
"IMP"
"VCN"
"ABS"
"OTV"
```

Here is the code that I have been trying, using `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dfmolten <- melt(df, id=c("ID_Study", "ID_Person", "ID_Project", "Category", "Orig", "Cur", "Nonc", "Logi", "Impa"))
dfcast <- cast(dfmolten, ID_Project~variable, fun.aggregate=sum)
```

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(ID_Study = c("dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6", 
                                 "dcb5e954-59a1-4bd0-bffc-c68ffbb320c6"), ID_Person = c("fe7abc94-bc8c-457b-acac-ab60b82d004b", 
                                                                                        "b35a7b92-9f68-496a-ad09-ce48d17b9435", "68869adf-70d4-4de6-9661-fb842b554c93", 
                                                                                        "7e6629c5-6deb-4760-aa04-95c391bfb364", "2c16dbd1-70ab-45bf-ad8d-e4b45d2af2e7", 
                                                                                        "fe7abc94-bc8c-457b-acac-ab60b82d004b", "7aa38d5c-b574-4d98-aa06-82a8d1b6f7e3", 
                                                                                        "d3e956b4-0dba-4cb7-be01-159320ca5950", "b35a7b92-9f68-496a-ad09-ce48d17b9435", 
                                                                                        "d9dadd24-e561-49c9-8611-e1382af622c6", "c92a3e2e-1ff4-4cc5-8482-aa9ff6c521bf", 
                                                                                        "eb7193ff-22b1-4626-8cc4-8dca70b69916", "8ccbc42f-8d87-4580-8d60-6d21c0a5ecc7", 
                                                                                        "e8ff9aae-6a37-49f0-aa4b-300c9d40078e", "7e6629c5-6deb-4760-aa04-95c391bfb364", 
                                                                                        "e8ff9aae-6a37-49f0-aa4b-300c9d40078e", "808f65f6-be9a-42de-9f2f-000ce9af99d9", 
                                                                                        "b0139033-f017-4e86-b41f-3785a9f4c0d7", "47c6a829-93ab-48f2-8a53-53c93778cc56", 
                                                                                        "fcd5e4f5-2803-4e84-8e9c-872504b6e261"), ID_Project = c("877ca787-5b4b-4c7a-9fb0-4f829c743bea", 
                                                                                                                                                "88f2028b-2720-4c29-9382-4b0991cf14a5", "7d8567bc-f51a-49b4-be9d-f9badcf70c03", 
                                                                                                                                                "13a1152b-4ce5-47f9-ae08-8c3ae3758290", "b0fef202-6657-4f69-9b4f-5026a30a8585", 
                                                                                                                                                "acd3b520-fa67-4832-aece-e7cf6f691ab4", "bcb6e7ae-f179-4986-ba8a-161d7effd1dc", 
                                                                                                                                                "1d5234a0-028a-4a71-9601-45d89f065662", "8cbcfb4c-c8dd-4a49-be04-fffc631edb19", 
                                                                                                                                                "2992f736-2423-4fc3-ba16-1b2007fdc384", "09453ff6-d717-45a0-b2b3-50b83c6e9c3e", 
                                                                                                                                                "82cce490-435b-4c0d-9c02-bed7514f8064", "b16864ce-0954-4a28-83cd-37a7c5924072", 
                                                                                                                                                "6d5a00dc-2928-4595-bcfd-e5497c4b4e6c", "e38e4062-4886-4800-8ae7-25258b30baa9", 
                                                                                                                                                "b09990e4-b86e-4b65-b8ca-4246bdcd9bb1", "97f1e263-cbad-42a7-a9be-492efd4cc653", 
                                                                                                                                                "10c814ba-aa91-498c-91f2-8fb9ccc3f105", "e387d312-00de-453a-a45c-529e72bf6b7c", 
                                                                                                                                                "4fca25ec-3b9c-488f-8edf-0d89b5aa1bb5"), Category = c("", "", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      "", "", "", "Work", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Work", "", "Academic", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      "", "", "Financial / Administrative", ""), Code = c("", "OTHB", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "", "T&E", "", "IMP", "", "", "VCN", "", "", "", "", "ABS", "OTV", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "VCN", "", "", "", ""), Rating = c(NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 8L, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 9L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Orig = c(5.17, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           5.33, 5.5, 5.67, 5.5, 5.17, 6.33, 4.67, 5.33, 6.17, 6.33, 5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           5.67, 6, 5.67, 6, 6.33, 5.83, 5.83, 3.67), Cur = c(5, 5.83, 6.33, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              5, 5.67, 5, 6.67, 5, 5.83, 6.17, 6, 5.5, 5.67, 5.33, 5, 5.33, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              5.33, 6, 6.5, 4.17), Nonc = c(2, 4.33, 4, 2.5, 2.17, 2, 4, 3.83, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            4.33, 3, 5.83, 3.33, 4.17, 3.67, 2.5, 3.67, 3.67, 4.83, 3.83, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            3.67), Logi = c(5.17, 5.17, 4.33, 4.17, 5.67, 5.17, 4.5, 4.67, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            5.17, 5.67, 4.5, 5.67, 3.67, 4, 4.17, 4, 5.17, 4.83, 4, 5.5), 
                    Impa = c(5.5, 4.83, 5.67, 4.5, 6, 5.5, 4.5, 4.33, 4.83, 5.33, 
                             6.5, 5.67, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4, 6, 5.17, 5.17, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                  -20L))
```

Comment: Are you after `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Code, values_from = Rating, names_repair = ~ replace(.x, .x == "", "dropme")) %>% select(-dropme)`?

Comment: That is a nice solution. The select command at the end didn't work for me, but I can always remove that dropme column seperately. Otherwise, this works well! Thank you very much. Feel free to add it as an answer.